# Efficient way for multiplying two numbers stored in vectors

Tags: c++

I currently am trying to figure out a method for multiplying two numbers stored in a vector. I have an addition function for arbitrarily large numbers. Is there a better method than just performing column multiplication between every digit and adding them together to a sum? Pseudocode for what I have down below.

```
vector<int> total;
int carry = 0; //int to store carrying value if needed

//initialize v1 and v2
for each element i of v1:
vector<int> temp;

    for each element j of v2:
          get v1[i] * v2[j] and compute how much carrying is needed
          push adjusted product to temp

    push carry to temp and reset carry
    add(temp, total)
```

Comment: Your pseudocode is so similar to C++, you may as well have just written C++.  It appears that you're trying to implement long multiplication.  The most significant speedup you could do right now is use something like `std::vector<uint64_t>` so that your "digits" are 64-bit values instead of presumably base-10.  Then you just need to implement a binary-to-decimal conversion if you want to output that.  Imagine how fast it is to multiply integers with thousands of bits when you can do chunks of 64 bits at a time.  Your O(N^2) loop will be 400 times faster by reducing 20 digits to 1 value.

Comment: Check out the [Karatsuba Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) it can reduce the number of multiplications you need to do. Combining it with @paddy's suggestion of moving to 64-bit should make a difference if your numbers are large.

Comment: yeah Karatsuba and just the whole wikipedia article on all of them would be good for the OP to read. Basically there are more efficient multiplication algorithms than the one you learn in elementary school: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm